# stop "Support for Office 2010 Ending Oct 13, 2020" messages when opening office docs

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

How do I stop "Support for Office 2010 Ending Oct 13, 2020" messages from showing in a yellow banner at the top of the screen when opening office docs?

I searched the registry for the message I get, and found it in the Office 14 area of the registry at key title "TargetedMessagingService".  There are settings but I have no idea what to set them to.  Anybody know how to disable the messages?

Comment: Upgrade to a newer version of Office. Not only is 2010 EoL, 2013 will be soon too. 2016 or even better, 2019 is definitely recommended.

Comment: [How do I turn off the end of support banner in office 2010 - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-turn-off-the-end-of-support-banner-in/4adeb8ae-e556-49f4-8da8-9934b38393b7)

Comment: Or use another tool, such as Open Office or LibreOffice.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I stop "Support for Office 2010 Ending Oct 13, 2020" messages from showing in a yellow banner at the top of the screen when opening office docs?

The only thing you need to do is create a key **UpgradeAdvertised** located `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\ClickToRun` with a value of **0**

If the key already exists then simply change the value from **1** to **0**.

While it's certainly possible to stop the notification and simply ignore the fact the product will no longer receive any security updates, you really should install a newer version of Office.  You will be unable to download Office 2010 after October 13th, 2020

Answer (score 2):

Regedit change value you may have to change all (`1` = `en-us`, `2` = `en` etc..

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\TargetedMessagingService\1:en-US:BizBar\Message\Body
```

Change `MessageScenario` from a value `6` to `0` to make the message disappear.

Comment: I have Office 14.0 (not 15.0 as in the other answer) and this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by DSmith is correct, but is only a temporary fix. When you shut down your PC, then start Office 2010 again, the updated registry entries will be automatically reset and the annoying message will reappear. To make your updates permanent, you need to deny ALL access to the affected registry entries once you've made the updates suggested by DSmith.

Answer (score 0):

Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2500073850-8412155-3312681868-1000\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\TargetedMessagingService\0:es-ES:BizBar\Message\Body

For me the key wasn't in the normal directory,I had to let it search for the key.

MessageScenario

Office 2010

Answer (score 0):

Re the suggested registry changes in 'Office\14.0

Both DSmith and Sanxs Sor are partly correct. As MarioBel66 implies:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is entirely formed dynamically from keys in `HKEY_USERS` at boot-up. Changes in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` are non-persistent, and will be replaced at machine boot-up by the entry in `HKEY_USERS`.

`S-1-5-21-2500073850-8412155-3312681868-1000` is a unique user ID specific to Sanxs Sor's logon on his/her machine.

So... To make a more permanent change, you have to find the relevant nag phrase (eg SUPPORT FOR OFFICE 2010) in the `HKEY_USERS` registry hive:

You will find it in a key that looks something like this:

```
 'HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-aaaaaaaaaa-bbbbbbb-cccccccccc-xxxx\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\TargetedMessagingService'
```

where `aaaaaaaaaa-bbbbbbb-cccccccccc-xxxx` is your user SID.  You can,  if you're interested, find your SID at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
```

To find your specific text (SUPPORT FOR OFFICE 2010), I suggest:

- Open the registry in regedit.exe AS AN ADMINISTRATOR
- Export `HKEY_USERS` hive to a .reg file by right-clicking `HKEY_USERS` and exporting it as a file with a suitable name.
- Change the file extension of that .reg file to .txt to avoid inadvertently importing a corrupt registry file into the registry
- Open the file with WordPad or your favourite text editor as regedit's own search engine is pretty hopeless I've found. WordPad's is pretty good.
- Find all instances of your chosen text.

The relevant snippets of registry (and there may be several per-user snippets) will look something like this:

```
[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-aaaaaaaaaa-bbbbbbb-cccccccccc-xxxx\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\TargetedMessagingService\0:en-US:BizBar\Message\Body]
"Theme"="Critical"
"Title"="SUPPORT FOR OFFICE 2010 HAS ENDED"
"Message"="Stay supported by moving to a current version of Office."
"MessageScenario"=dword:00000006
```

And..

```
 [HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-aaaaaaaaaa-bbbbbbb-cccccccccc-xxxx\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\TargetedMessagingService\1:en-US:BizBar\Message\Body]
"Theme"="Critical"
"Title"="SUPPORT FOR OFFICE 2010 HAS ENDED"
"Message"="Stay supported by moving to a current version of Office."
"MessageScenario"=dword:00000006
```

etc

In each snippet, there is a key 'MessageScenario' with the value of 00000006.
This value needs changed to:

```
 00000000
```

You can find these snippets in the registry and edit MessageScenario value individually.  Or, If you're very very careful, you can form your snippets into a single text file.  Add a ‘Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00’ header to this file, followed with a blank line, followed by your edited registry snippets.  It should look something like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

 [HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-aaaaaaaaaa-bbbbbbb-cccccccccc-xxxx\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\TargetedMessagingService\0:en-US:BizBar\Message\Body]
"Theme"="Critical"
"Title"="SUPPORT FOR OFFICE 2010 HAS ENDED"
"Message"="Stay supported by moving to a current version of Office."
"MessageScenario"=dword:00000000

 [HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-aaaaaaaaaa-bbbbbbb-cccccccccc-xxxx\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\TargetedMessagingService\1:en-US:BizBar\Message\Body]
"Theme"="Critical"
"Title"="SUPPORT FOR OFFICE 2010 HAS ENDED"
"Message"="Stay supported by moving to a current version of Office."
"MessageScenario"=dword:00000000
```

Save this file with an appropriate filename with a .reg file extension. Exit file.

Provided you haven’t changed the default action for double clicking .reg files, double-clicking the file will bring up a warning prompt. Say OK.  If you HAVE changed that default action, right-click the file and choose ‘Merge’

Be aware that this reg file will be ONLY suitable for your machine as it is SID specific.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution which has now worked for me with two separate PCs (and is still working after several weeks and numerous reboots) has been to simply uninstall Office 2010 and then reinstall it using the original installation media.

In both cases I had the original CD installation media (and the product key which came with the CD). I do not know whether this would also work if Office 2010 came pre-installed with the PC.

Answer (score 0):

My situation is slightly different:

- My Office 2010 version is 14.0
- The warning banner isn't yellow but red
- The support ended in March 2021 not October 2020
- After editing the value for key `MessageScenario` to 0 it gets changed back to 6
- After deleting the `TargetedMessagingService` node it gets restored

The solution which worked was to find **`TimeToNextcall`**.
This appears four times in the registry, the first is in

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\TargetedMessagingService\0:en-US:BizBar\Message\Header`

and had the value `2021-04-13T15:31:29Z`. After that time had passed, a warning was issued and the entry's date was changed to the next day.

- **I edited the year to be** `2035`

The other keys are similar, and I only had to edit the two in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. The other two in `HKEY_USERS` were changed automatically.

This has silenced the annoying, intermittent, and questionably intrusive warning. After all, if I am out of support, why is MS tampering with my machine?